# turkish character encoding in PDF

Tags: delphi, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to use turkish characters in pdf which is created by rad studio xe7 and android application.

```
 Writer.Write(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('/BaseFont /Helvetica' +  sLineBreak));;
 Writer.Write(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('/Encoding /MacRomanEncoding' + sLineBreak));
```

In above code, which encoding type has to be used?

Comment: What component / library do you use to create the pdf? The answer is probably specific to that lib... (AFAIK XE7 doesn't have built in lib to create PDF so you either use some thirdparty or in-house tool).

Comment: You just can not do this like that. Encoding in PDFs have only a small set of code pages, like WinAnsi1252 or MacRoman. For other encodings (like turkish), you need either to use Unicode, or to define your own set, which is a huge work.